# Как найти элемент в конкретной области?

Tags: javascript, html

Вот можно найти элемент в документе:

```js
document.getElementById("id");
document.getElementsByClassName("class");
```

А можно ли найти его там в конкретном диве?
Например:

```html
<div id="id">
<p class="class_1"></p>
<p id="id_1"></p>
<p class="class_1"></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно.
Этот пример возвращает список всех элементов с классом 'class_1' , которые находятся непосредственно в элементах-контейнерах с тегом div, имеющих id = 'id':

```
let el = document.querySelector('#id');
let matches = el.querySelectorAll('div.class_1');
```